# local .csv file using dygraph library

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I am trying to use dygraph for javascript.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="dygraph-combined.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="graphdiv2"
  style="width:500px; height:300px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  g2 = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("graphdiv2"),
    "C:/temperatures.csv", // path to CSV file   ***This file is local file in my C: drive***
    {}          // options
  );
</script>
</body>
```

temperatures.csv is a local file on my machine. I read couple of posts that state .csv file has to be on a remote machine. I wonder is there a way to read local .csv file. Can you suggest some solution to this please. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In general, you cannot load local files via JavaScript. This would be a huge security hole.

If you want to enable this for local development, you can run Chrome with the `--allow-file-access-from-files` command-line flag. I assume other browsers have similar options. You may also need to add a "file://" before the "c:\" in your path.

Alternatively, consider spinning up a lightweight HTTP server for local development. Common choices are Python's [`http.server`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) (run `python -m http.server`) or the [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) node module.

Answer (score 3):

This works fine for me on Firefox with the CSV file in the same directory as the HTML file. Then just open the HTML file locally as a file://whatever and pass "input.csv" to dygraphs.

No turning off of security options needed - but I don't know about Chrome.

Comment: Not anymore, firefox for file://whatever these days gives me: "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource"